# Multiply two ranges against each other - Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to solve the 4th problem in Project Euler but I've hit a problem. I need to multiply two ranges against each other but I'm not sure how to do this with Elixir. Here is what I'm working with:

```
  def is_palindrome?(n) do
    Integer.to_string(n) == Integer.to_string(n)|> String.reverse
  end

  def multiply do
    range_1 = 100..999
    range_2 = 100..999

    for n <- range_1, n * range_2, do: n |> is_palindrome? |> Enum.max
  end
```

I'm getting this error back

```
(ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
```

How can I multiply the two ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take elements from the list (`<-`) twice if you want to multiply each element to every other element. `is_palindrome?` should used as a filter in the `for`. Finally, `Enum.max` should be outside the `for`.

```
defmodule A do
  def is_palindrome?(n) do
    Integer.to_string(n) == Integer.to_string(n)|> String.reverse
  end

  def multiply do
    range_1 = 100..999
    range_2 = 100..999

    Enum.max for n <- range_1, m <- range_2, is_palindrome?(n * m), do: n * m
  end
end
```

```
iex(1)> A.multiply
906609
```